# Cut on my car's tyre

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I noticed that my car's back tyre has some damage. It doesn't look that worse but not sure if I should replace it. my car is Kia Rio.[image: Tyre-pics]

Comment: Tire flanks are constantly churned on by the weight of the car while driving. This is the most delicate part of a tire and the tire needs to be replaced when the flank is even slightly damaged.

Comment: @Janka - You're saying if you get one little scratch on the sidewall you should replace the tire? While the sidewall is most assuredly the weakest part of the tire, it doesn't mean it's delicate. It can stand up to abuse. In most cases, as long as the sidewall or tread doesn't get out of shape (bubble or deformed), there's no issue. There is rubber there for a reason. Just because a little bit rubs off doesn't mean you need to replace the tire.

Comment: Well, the picture above certainly isn't "a little bit rubbed off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the picture it is hard to tell how deep that damage goes, but it certainly doesn't look like a minor scuff. I'd certainly be concerned about using this tyre and it would be on my mind say whilst traveling on fast roads etc

In this case I would advise that the tyre be replaced. Damage like this certainly would be cause for the vehicle to fail an MOT test, here in the UK anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's not that dangerous, maybe but the anxiety is always there. I am gonna replace asap.

Comment: It's the hidden damage that is the issue - best to replace it - good decision.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sidewall damage evident in the photo, I would be inclined to replace the tire.

Even though your photo is clear, it is not clear how much rubber has been removed, and that is why an in-person inspection would be good. Certainly, if you are near any kind of cord in the sidewall, I would replace.

A sidewall failure can be quite disconcerting, and can happen quickly.  It may not be an issue today, but as the tire wears, and under conditions such as mild underinflation, or high temperatures, the sidewall would be more likely to fail with some thickness removed, as the photo evidenced.

Keep in mind that the sidewall in that region is the thinnest portion of the tire, and they are not repairable.

Comment: Almost everyone suggested me to replace the tyre and I have already done it so. Peace of mind.